# Как правильно вытащить картинки из БД?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

У меня приложение с картой яндекс. По нажатию на маркер появляется активити с картинками нажатого места в виде слайдера. http://codetheory.in/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager-pageradapter/ вот тут картинки представляются в массиве, так как они у него в res

```
imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);
```

а предварительно их `id` записываются в массив

```
int[] mResources = {
  R.drawable.first,
  R.drawable.second,
  R.drawable.third,
  R.drawable.fourth,
  R.drawable.fifth,
  R.drawable.sixth
};
```

Но у меня они все в БД.

Мне в массиве вытаскивать из базы, или тут

```
imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);
```

или вообще по другому?

Ведь еще надо учитывать на какой именно маркер нажали, потому что у каждой метки свои картинки.

Comment: по запросу к БД вы получите курсор с затребованными данными - фактически массив подходящих под выборку значений. Дальше работайте с этим курсором, как считаете нужным. Читая данные напрямую из курсора, скопировав в какой то массив или еще как ..

Answer (score 3):

Я бы вам советовал не использовать их Id для хранения указателя на картинку в бд. Лучше используйте заранее выбранные имена, что бы потом можно было по имени найти ресурс. Просто в противном случае можете нарваться на ситуацию, когда Id перегенерируются, а в базе останутся старые. При обновлении приложения например.
Организуйте базу так, что бы конкретному айди маркера соответствовал набор записей в бд, потом получайте по айди маркера массив нужных вам имен ресурсов, а по именам доставайте ресурсы.